# Optimize jquery add and remove class

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

There must be a solution somewhere, but I could not understand.
My problem is simple, but do not know how to optimize it.

I've got simple code of tab navigation (to view content)

```
$(function(){
    $('#tab_o_nas article').hide();
    $('#tab-1').show();
    $('#opcja-1').addClass('active_tab');

    $('#opcja-1').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active_tab');
        $('#opcja-2').removeClass('active_tab');
        $('#opcja-3').removeClass('active_tab');
        $('#opcja-4').removeClass('active_tab');
        $('#tab_o_nas article').hide();
        $('#tab-1').show();
        return false;
    });

    $('#opcja-2').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active_tab');
        $('#opcja-1').removeClass('active_tab');
        $('#opcja-3').removeClass('active_tab');
        $('#opcja-4').removeClass('active_tab');
        $('#tab_o_nas article').hide();
        $('#tab-2').show();
        return false;
    });

    $('#opcja-3').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active_tab');
        $('#opcja-1').removeClass('active_tab');
        $('#opcja-2').removeClass('active_tab');
        $('#opcja-4').removeClass('active_tab');
        $('#tab_o_nas article').hide();
        $('#tab-3').show();
        return false;
    });

    $('#opcja-4').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active_tab');
        $('#opcja-1').removeClass('active_tab');
        $('#opcja-2').removeClass('active_tab');
        $('#opcja-3').removeClass('active_tab');
        $('#tab_o_nas article').hide();
        $('#tab-4').show();
        return false;
    });

  });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4AYMs/)

Is there any other way to optimize this addClass and removeClass?
To get shorter code?

Comment: use `$(this)` and a class for each tab

Comment: Stop (Mis)Using Return False http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should fix the markup of your navigation ordered-list (the anchors should be inside the `<li>`s, not the other way around):

```
<ol id="nav_o_nas">
        <li id="opcja-1"><a href="#">tab 1</a></li>
        <li id="opcja-2"><a href="#">tab 2</a></li>
        <li id="opcja-3"><a href="#">tab 3</a></li>
        <li id="opcja-4"><a href="#">tab 4</a></li>
</ol>
```

Then, you can add a simple binder to the list, which delegates to the anchors, finds the index of the item clicked, and toggles the classes and articles appropriately:

```
$('#nav_o_nas').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // should be used instead of return false;

    // get the index of the clicked link (0-3)    
    var index = $('#nav_o_nas a').index(this);

    // select all list items, remove the class, target the correct link, add the class    
    $('#nav_o_nas li').removeClass('active_tab').eq(index).addClass('active_tab');
    // hide all articles, show the correct article
    $('article').hide().eq(index).show();
});
```

See it working here http://jsfiddle.net/4AYMs/2/

Comment: Many thanks for other solutions, but this code seems to me to be the most suitable :)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use .toggleClass()

```
$('.btn').toggleClass('active');
```

I cannot view your fiddle from my place atm, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some classes to your markup. Then you are able to do this:

```
$('.tab-class').click(function() {

    // removes all active_tab classes
    $('.tab-class').removeClass('active_tab');

    // adds the active_tab class to the current element
    $(this).addClass('active_tab');

    // hides your articles (another class is recommended)
    $('article').hide();

    // get the number of the clicked item from its id via replace
    var nr = $(this).attr('id').replace('opcja-', '');

    // shows related tab with the number of the clicked li 
    $('#tab-' + nr).show();

    return false;
});
```

See this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4AYMs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You do 4 things:

1. remove every element class 'active_tab'
2. add class to clicked element
3. hide all articles
4. show article with the same number as opcja's number

So it's pretty universal, you could do it with 1 function, not 4 functions:

```
$(function () {
    $('#tab_o_nas article').hide();
    $('#tab-1').show();
    $('#opcja-1').addClass('active_tab');

    var links = $('#nav_o_nas li');

    links.click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            selOption = $this.attr('id'),
            selNumber = (selOption.split('-'))[1];

        links.removeClass('active_tab');
        $this.addClass('active_tab');
        $('#tab_o_nas article').hide();
        $('#tab-'+selNumber).show();
        return false;
    });

});
```

I also changed your html a little bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/4AYMs/3/

Answer (score 0):

This is complete shorter code like in demo

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#nav_o_nas li').click(function(){
     $('#nav_o_nas li').removeClass('active_tab');
        $(this).addClass('active_tab');
        var this_id = $(this).attr('id');

        var arry = this_id.split("-"); 

        $('#tab_o_nas article').hide();
        $('#tab-'+arry[1]).show();

 });

$('#tab_o_nas article').hide();
$('#tab-1').show();
$('#opcja-1').addClass('active_tab');
});
```

Hope this will help you..